# void Test::printxy(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Test' to 'Test &' in const class

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have write a very simple program about const class, however, when I compile, there is a error:void Test::printxy(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Test' to 'Test &'

The program is as below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class  Test
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Test(int a = 1, int b = 1) : x(a), y(b) {};
    void printxy();
};
void Test::printxy()
{
    cout << "x*y=" << x*y << endl;
}
void main(void)
{
    const Test t;
    t.printxy();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why are so many questions on this site using `void main`?

Comment: @remyabel : I wonder that myself.  Even Herbert Schildt's book (at least the portion I could see on amazon.com) gets it right.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `printxy` member function is not declared `const`, it cannot be invoked on a constant object. You need to declare the member function `const` like this:

```
class Test
{
    void printxy() const;
    //             ^^^^^

    // ...
};

void Test::printxy() const
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to call the non-`const` function `printxy()` on the `const` obejct `t`. You are missing a `const` after the method declaration:

```
class Test {
    // ...
    void printxy() const;
};

void Test::printxy() const {
    // ...
}
```